# Standard idiom for walking along a list in C

Tags: c, coding-style, linked-list, idioms

I am reading "The practice of programming" and it says that a standard loop for walking along a list in C is:

```
for (p=list;p != NULL;p=p->next)
...
```

My question is how does NULL work? I myself have used this in programs, but never paused to ponder over how it works.

I suppose, NULL must be a standard macro defined in a very basic header file like stdio.h
but what it is defined as? Is it?

```
#define MACRO 0
```

here how does 0 work when we compare a pointer to 0. This 0 could be a valid memory address 0, then how do we distinguish to say that we actually mean invalid address i.e. the pointer has a logical empty value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined as 0, yes. The thing is that 0 is *not* a valid memory address; computers are actually put together such that trying to access that address is an error.

Try running this program on your machine, if you want to insist that 0 is a legal address:

```
#import <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int *p = 0;
  printf("No read error: %d\n", *p);
  *p = 1;
  printf("No write error either\n");
}
```

Comment: To be precise, it's almost always defined as `((void *) 0)`. Only a very lame implementation would define it as plain `0`, which would suppress compile-time errors when comparing `NULL` to a non-pointer type.

Comment: I'm nearly certain there are architectures on which zero is a valid address. NULL = 0 cast to pointer is a convention, nothing else. Enables the if (ptr) idiom.

Comment: It certainly is a valid *physical* address, on all architectures I'm aware of.

Comment: It is a valid *physical* address and the processor can access it; but the MMU is generally programmed to keep user processes away from it, as evidenced by the example program above. Pedantry aside, on the most common architectures, my statements above stand. The standard certainly allows more exotic implementations, but many folks will never encounter one; the straightforward implementation in which NULL is really the address 0 is most common by an overwhelming margin.

Comment: @Ernest Your example program does not prove that 0 is not a valid address - if it "proves" anything, it is that dereferencing the NULL pointer gives undefined behaviour - it could actually access physical address zero! In fact on a (say) CP/M machine I'd expect it would do exactly that. Not everyone is working on machines with MMUs and VM.

Comment: No, computers are not put together to error on access to address 0. OSes may have restrictions on mapping address 0 (e.g. `mmap_min_addr` on Linux), but there may be some uses of mapping address 0 (IIRC, the VDM (Windows' DOS box) does map virtual page 0, the alternative would be faulting on every access to page 0).

Comment: :) I'd say half of my work is done on C implementations where 0 is most certainly a valid address, but NULL is still mapping to ((void*)0). The linker does its best not to put anything at that address, but it effectively wastes a byte of memory...

Answer (score 4):

The C FAQ has a whole section on [NULL pointers](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html). A short summary:

- the **constant** int value zero (`0`), in a context where the compiler knows a pointer is
  needed, is treated as the "null pointer": a pointer value known to not point at a valid
  memory address
- this only applies to constants, not any integer values; for example, assigning zero to
  a variable, and then using that as a pointer, does not guarantee the value will be
  a null pointer
- the real address may or may not be zero; the compiler may translate it to another
  address
- several standard library headers define the macro `NULL`, either as a plain `0` or
  cast into a pointer: `((void *) 0)` (the C standard allows either)